# jQuery Jigowatt file upload

Tags: jquery, webforms

When i bought an HTML5-template form ThemeForest, there was a contact-form (which uses jquery.jigowatt) included.

Now i want to add a file-input to that form, but jigowatt doesn't send the file to the php-script.

Can anybody help me?

Here you have the code that is now in the jigowatt.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#contactform').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
            $('#message').hide();

            $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');

            $.post(action, {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                phone: $('#phone').val(),
                comments: $('#comments').val(),
                title: $('#title').val(),
                cv: $('#cv').val()
            },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform').find('img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');
            });

        });

        return false;

    });

});
```